# A factorization game

Tags: polynomials, finite-fields, factorization

This is a toy version of a [problem I have posted recently](https://mathoverflow.net/q/330636/9924).

Imagine playing the following game. You choose a polynomial $B$ over a finite field $\mathbb F_p$, of degree $\deg B\le p-1$ (where $p$ is a large prime). I can modify your polynomial any way I wish, except that I am not allowed to add or change monomials of degree exceeding $0.9p$. My goal is to make the resulting polynomial split completely into linear factors; if I fail to do so, you win.

- What polynomial $B$ will you start the game with to win?
- Is there a comprehensible classification of all winning (for the first player) polynomials?

---

As an illustration, if I can change only monomials of degree smaller than $(p-10)/4$, then you win by choosing $B(x):=x^{p-1}-nx^{p-3}$, where $n$ is a quadratic non-residue modulo $p$. To see this, suppose that $R$ is a polynomial of degree $d$ such that $Q(x):=x^{p-1}-nx^{p-3}+R(x)$ splits into linear factors, and show that $d\ge(p-10)/4$. Writing $D(x):=(Q(x),x^{p-1}-1)$, we have
\begin{align*}
  D(x) 
    &= (nx^{p-3}-R(x)+1,x^{p-1}-1) \\
    &= (nx^{p-1}-x^2R(x)+x^2,x^{p-1}-1) \\
    &= (x^2R(x)-x^2-n,x^{p-1}-1),
\end{align*}
so that $\deg D\le d+2$. On the other hand, since $Q(x)$ splits into linear factors, it is a divisor of the polynomial 
  $$ (Q(x),x^p-x)^3(x^3Q(x))''' = (Q(x),x^p-x)^3(x^3R(x))'''. $$
Since the degree of $(Q(x),x^p-x)$ does not exceed $\deg D+1$, we conclude that either
  $$ p-1 = \deg Q \le 3(\deg D+1) + \deg R \le 4d+9, $$
or $(x^3R(x))'''=0$. In the former case we are done, in the latter case $R=0$ and $Q(x)=x^{p-1}-nx^{p-3}$, contrary to the choice of $n$ and the assumption that $Q$ splists into linear factors.

It should be possible to push this argument to replace $(p-10)/4$ with $p/2+O(1)$, but I cannot see how to get all the way up to $0.9p$.

Comment: Working symbolically write $B=\prod_i X_i x + Y_i$. After equating coefficients you have $2 \deg(B)$ unknowns and $\deg(B) - 0.9p$ equations. If the system is overdetermined likely it won't have solutions.

Comment: @joro: The system is actually greatly underdetermined, as the number of variables $2\deg B$ is much larger than the number of equations $\deg B-0.9p$ - or have you meant anything else?

Comment: OK, I didn't examine it carefully. In general greatly underdetermined system will have solution over F_p, unless there is some hidden reason.

Comment: @joro: Exactly - my question is about these possible hidden reasons!

Comment: Try this for a simulation. Let you and A take turns. Given p, A starts on turn 1 and names coefficient for p-1. You name root 1. On turn j A names coefficient for (power of) p-j, and then you name root j. How far can you go before you lose (no way that your product of linear factors will match the named polynomial of A)? My guess is you can simulate a few turns for small p and extrapolate to large p. Gerhard "But Don't Game The Results" Paseman, 2019.05.07.

Comment: One "hidden reason" is symmetry: you have only about $4^p$ ways to choose your roots because the permutations do not matter and I have about $p^{p/10}$ ways to choose my top coefficients, so I wouldn't even bother to think if $p$ is large, just roll a $p$-sided die.

Comment: @fedja: This is more or less the observation made also by Fedor Petrov as a comment to my previous post. Unfortunately, it does not answer the question: I'd like to see even one, but *specific* polynomial. My hope is that the proof for this one polynomial can be extended  to yield a general necessary condition that the head / middle part of a fully reducible polynomial must satisfy. Very loosely speaking, I'd like to have a kind of the Descartes rule of signs for the finite fields settings.